Dev env is skipping
I'm looking for the reason why the DEV Environment is not executed immediately after the Testing stage. The general rule is that I have two pipelines: the first one does only Testing, then it triggers the second pipeline, which should perform the actual deployment using Terraform on the Dev Environment. The first part works, i.e., the first pipeline triggers the second one correctly, but the triggered one does not start the Dev Environment.
pipeline.yaml
name: MySource
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Library
      ref: test/pipeline    
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - test/pipeline
parameters:
  - name: pipelineMode
    displayName: Pipeline Mode
    type: string
    default: main
    values:
      - auto
      - feature
      - main
      - release

# rest of the code goes here

It should trigger that one below:
dependant_pipeline.yaml
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Library
      ref: test/pipeline
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: test-triggered
      project: DEV
      source: 'library'
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - test/pipeline
parameters:
  - name: pipelineMode
    displayName: Pipeline Mode
    type: string
    default: main
    values:
      - auto
      - feature
      - main
      - release
extends:
  template: main-pipeline.yml
  parameters:
    devEnv: dev
    devVar: dev_variables.yml
    deployEnvTemp: deploy.yml


Taking a very quick look at your code I see a few problems in dependant_pipeline.yaml:

A few parameters are missing: devEnvironment, devVariables, deployEnvironmentTemplate and deployParameters

You forgot to pass the pipelineMode parameter to /templates/build.yml



Rui, could we move to the chat? I have to many templates ingested, it might be messed to explain, and some of them I need to cut anyway.

@Kreg I suggest you fix some of the issues I mentioned and then create a minimal, reproducible example to solve the issue(s) you find one at a time. No offense but I don't want to spend hours trying to figure out what's wrong in the middle of so many templates, specially knowing you're not showing the whole templates in some cases.

I understand, so I add more templates which are called. I hope it helps, if not let me know what is missing.

@Kreg you still need to fix the issues I mentioned, e.g. pass the pipelineMode parameter to /templates/options.yml.

I added changes based on your comment (If I understood it correctly), however still Dev env. is skipping. I edited main question by adding my changes at the bottom.

@Kreg I still don't understand where are the variables I mentioned in my answer.

Those changes are in the main-pipeline.yaml, I added it also.

I get lost myself :( no progress from several days. I edited my main question.

When specifying the environment on a deployment job in YAML pipeline, do not only provide the environment name. If you only provide the environment name, the pipeline will not use the resources added in the environment for the deployment job.
To let the deployment job can use the resources in the specified environment, you can do like as any of the following configurations:

Specify the resource type using the 'resourceType' key. For example, in below sample, the deployment will use all the VM type resources from the specified environment. It will generate a deployment job for each VM type resource.
jobs:
- deployment: deployB
  environment:
    name: ${{ variables.myEnv }}
    resourceType: virtualMachine



You also can use the 'resourceName' key to set the deployment only use a particular resource. For example, in below sample, the deployment will only use the resource "Ubuntu2204-01" from the specified environment. It will generate only one deployment job for the specified resource.
jobs:
- deployment: deployB
  environment:
    name: ${{ variables.myEnv }}
    resourceName: Ubuntu2204-01





Thank you also Bright for your time and support. The problem was with passing PipelineMode parameter. It works now.
